# Kafka - Retention period Parameter

Tags: apache-kafka

Trying to understand the logic behind retention period in Apache Kafka. Please help me to understand the situation for the below scenarios.

1. If retention period is set as 0, what will happen? Will all records be deleted?
2. If we delete the retention parameter itself, will it take the default value?

Comment: Note: the tag for [confluent-kafka] is only meant to be used for Clients based on librdkafka.

Answer (score 7):

1. Kafka doesn't allow you to set the retention period as zero, in units of hours. It has to be at-least 1. In case, you set it to zero, you'll get the following error message, and the broker won't start.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed:
> log.retention.ms must be unlimited (-1) or, equal or greater than 1

You can still set it to zero while using the parameters `log.retention.minutes` or `log.retention.ms`

- Now, let's come to the point of data deletion. In this situation, the old data won't likely get deleted even after the set retention (say 1 hr, or 1 min) has expired, because one more variable in `server.properties` called `log.segment.bytes` plays a major role there. The value of `log.segment.bytes` is set to 1GB by default. Kafka only performs deletion on a closed segment. So, once a log segment has reached 1GB, only then it is closed, and only after that the retention kicks in. So, you need to reduce the size of `log.segment.bytes` to some approximate value which is atmost the size of the cumulative investion volume of the data that you are planning to retain for that short duration. E.g. if your retention period is 10 min, and you get roughly 1 MB of data per minute, then you can set the `log.segment.bytes=10485760` which is `1024 x 1024 x 10`. You can find an example of how retention is dependent both on the data ingestion and time in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473270/kafka-configuration-for-only-seeing-last-5-minutes-of-data/51477919#51477919) thread.
- To test this, we can try a small experiment. Let's start Zookeeper and Kafka, create a topic called `test`and change its retention period to zero.

  ```
  1) nohup ./zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties &
  2) nohup ./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties &
  3) ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
  4) ./kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name test --alter --add-config log.retention.ms=0
  ```
- Now if we insert sufficient records using Kafka-console-producer, even after 2-3 minutes, we'll see the records are not deleted. But now, let's change the `log.segment.bytes` to 100 bytes.

  ```
  5) ./kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name test --alter --add-config segment.bytes=100
  ```
- Now, almost immediately we'll see that old records are getting deleted from Kafka.

2. Yes. As it happens with every Kafka parameter in `server.properties`, if we delete/comment out a property, the default value for that property kicks in. I think, the default retention period is 1 week.

Comment: According to documentation retention time is 1 week (property `log.retention.hours=168`. It can be change on broker site, but different value can also be set for each topic

Comment: @wardziniak I already mentioned the default retention period in the answer, but I think that adding info about the topic specific params would make the answer complete. I'll update my answer with more details. Thanks.

Comment: "even after 2-3 minutes, we'll see the records are not deleted" -- This is because the segment file is still active, right?

Comment: @cricket Yes, that's the reason.