# Kafka topic record retention policies not clear

Tags: apache-kafka, retention

From Kafka Docs I got interested and tried the following 2 retention types **together**

### log.retention.bytes:

> The maximum size of the log before deleting it
> Type: longDefault: -1Valid Values:Importance: highUpdate Mode: cluster-wide

### log.retention.ms

> The number of milliseconds to keep a log file before deleting it (in
> milliseconds), If not set, the value in log.retention.minutes is used.
> If set to -1, no time limit is applied. Type: longDefault: nullValid
> Values:Importance: highUpdate Mode: cluster-wide

AS

1. log.retention.bytes = 1Gb
2. log.retention.ms    = 7 days

---

#### Problem Situation

I have currently on my topic all messages belonging two different log files both of which are < 1GB

Lets say log.1 files has 400 MB of messages with oldest message > 7 days old.

**which is on the top of**

log.2 file has 500 MB with newest message > 7 days old.

I understand kafka would clean up all records belonging to log.2 file in other words remove this log from the topic.

What happens to the records in the log.1 which are older than 7 days?

Answer (score 2):

There are two properties which defines message retention in Kafka - `log.retention.bytes` and `log.retention.ms` (per topic per partition level). The strategy for data removal works on `FIFO` basic, i.e., the message which was pushed to a topic first would be deleted first.

You have rightly said that the default values for the same are:

```
log.retention.bytes = 1Gb (per topic per partition)
log.retention.ms = 7 days (per topic)
```

It means that whichever limit is breached first, would lead to data purge in Kafka.

For example, let's assume that the size of messages in your topic takes 500 MB of space (which is less than `log.retention.bytes`) but older than 7 days (i.e. greater than the default `log.retention.ms`). In this case the data older than 7 days would be purged (on `FIFO` basis).

Likewise, if, for a given topic, the space occupied by the messages exceeds the `log.retention.bytes` but are not older than `log.retention.ms`, in this case too, the data would be purged (on `FIFO` basis).

Concept of making data expire is called as `Cleanup` & **the messages on a topic are not immediately removed after they are consumed/expired**. What happens in the background is, once either of the limit is breached, the messages are marked deleted. There are 3 logs cleanup policies in Kafka - `DELETE` (default), `COMPACT`, `DELETE AND COMPACT`. Kafka Log Cleaner does log compaction, a pool of background compaction threads.

To turn on compaction for a topic use topic config `log.cleanup.policy=compact`. To set delay to start compacting records after they are written use topic config `log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms`. **Records won’t get compacted until after this period.** The setting gives consumers time to get every record. This could be reason that older messages are not getting deleted immediately. You can check the value of property for compaction delay.

Below links might be helpful:

- https://medium.com/@sunny_81705/kafka-log-retention-and-cleanup-policies-c8d9cb7e09f8
- http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-architecture-log-compaction/index.html
- https://www.learningjournal.guru/courses/kafka/kafka-foundation-training/broker-configurations/

Comment: Problem is when those 500 MB belong to the same log file on kafka server and contain messages older than 7 days? They simply stay there?

Comment: Concept of making data expire is called as `Cleanup` & the messages on a topic are not immediately removed after they are consumed/expired. What happens in the background is, once either of the limit is breached, the messages are marked deleted. There are 3 logs cleanup policies in Kafka - `DELETE` (default), `COMPACT`, `DELETE AND COMPACT`. `Kafka Log Cleaner` does log compaction, a pool of background compaction threads. https://medium.com/@sunny_81705/kafka-log-retention-and-cleanup-policies-c8d9cb7e09f8 & http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-architecture-log-compaction/index.html

Comment: To turn on compaction for a topic use topic config `log.cleanup.policy=compact`.

To set delay to start compacting records after they are written use topic config `log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms`. **Records won’t get compacted until after this period.** The setting gives consumers time to get every record. This could be reason your older messages are not getting deleted. You can check the value of property for compaction delay `log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms`.

Comment: This might help: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/51477919/4245859`

Comment: I got that...but my scenario is actually a mix of 2 logs files both having records older than 7 days one having partially older than 7 days other completely older than 7 days...updated my problem statement in the question.

Comment: @Bitswazsky, I reckon @Anirudh is interested in knowing why is that the expired messages not getting deleted. It's most likely because the `cleanup` has not kicked in yet.

Comment: @Anirudh Please check my comment above. That might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks but that comment doesnt help as in your comment its about only about __log.retention.bytes__ and not both __log.retention.bytes__ and __log.retention.ms__ together.

Comment: Kafka will close a log segment either when the size limit is reached or when the time limit is reached, whichever comes first. By default, there is no setting for `log.segment.ms`, which results in only closing log segments by size.

Comment: @Anirudh, Slight correction on my part, the `log.retention.bytes` works on **partition level and not on topic level** . You can refer to this tutorial for this here - https://www.learningjournal.guru/courses/kafka/kafka-foundation-training/broker-configurations/

Answer (score 1):

I'm paraphrasing here, from the relevant section of a book, ***Kafka - Definitive Guide***. It'll most likely clear your doubt.

**log.retention.bytes** : This denotes the total number of bytes of messages retained per partition. So, if we have a topic with 8 partitions, and `log.retention.bytes` is set to 1GB, then the amount of data retained for the topic will be 8GB at most. This means if we ever choose to increase the number of partitions for a topic, total amount of data retained will also increase.

**log.retention.ms** : The most common configuration for how long Kafka will retain messages is by time. The default is specified in the configuration file using the `log.retention.hours` parameter, and it is set to 168 hours, or one week. However, there are two other parameters allowed, `log.retention.minutes` and `log.retention.ms`. All three of these specify the same configuration—the amount of time after which messages may be deleted—but the recommended parameter to use is `log.retention.ms`, as the smaller unit size will take precedence if more than one is specified. This will make sure that the value set for `log.retention.ms` is always the one used. If more than one is specified, the smaller unit size will take precedence.

**Retention By Time and Last Modified Times** : Retention by time is performed by examining the last modified time (mtime) on each log segment file on disk. Under normal cluster operations, this is the time that the log segment was closed, and represents the timestamp of the last message in the file. However, when using administrative tools to move partitions between brokers, this time is not accurate and will result in excess retention for these partitions.

**Configuring Retention by Size and Time** : If you have specified a value for both `log.retention.bytes` and `log.retention.ms` (or another parameter for retention by time), messages may be removed when either criteria is met. For example, if `log.retention.ms` is set to 86400000 (1 day) and `log.retention.bytes` is set to 1000000000 (1 GB), it is possible for messages that are less than 1 day old to get deleted if the total volume of messages over the course of the day is greater than 1 GB. Conversely, if the volume is less than 1 GB, messages can be deleted after 1 day even if the total size of the partition is less than 1 GB.

Comment: __Conversely, if the volume is less than 1 GB, messages can be deleted after 1 day even if the total size of the partition is less than 1 GB.__  Not clear about what you mean here?

Comment: Well, all this paragraph trying to say is, given we have both these parameters set to the values (1 day and 1GB), data can get deleted earlier than the retention period if the size is exceeded. Similarly data can also get removed if the size limit is not yet reached, but the retention period is exceeded. So, out of these two settings whichever is satisfied first, will take effect.

Comment: I gathered that^^..however what I ask is an edge case perhaps, I updated my problem statement in the question to make it more clearer.